# visability:hidden freezes animation inside iframe in Chrome and Opera (WebKit likely)

Tags: html, css, animation, iframe, webkit

I have page with animations and post it on third party site where it's placed in an `iframe`.

Sometimes the `iframe`'s wrapper div changes CSS `visibility` property to `hidden` and when it returns to visible, the animation inside the iframe becomes frozen.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Testing iFrame CSS Animation when visibility is toggled</title>
   <style>.invisible { visibility: hidden; }</style>
</head>
<body>
   <h2>iFrame:</h2>
   
   <div id="thirdPartyWrapper">
<iframe id="myiframe" style="border:2px solid red;" width="500" height="500" src="http://www.aziznatour.com/temp/iframe-animation/iframe.php"></iframe>
</div>
   <br>
   <button>Toggle iFrame Visibility</button>
   
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
   <script>
      $('button').on("click", function(){
          $("#thirdPartyWrapper").toggleClass('invisible');
      });
   </script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

---

[image: iframe visibility stops animation]

[GIF in Dev Tools](https://i.imgur.com/2EL0Pm7.gifv)

If I hover animated `div` in Developer Tools it seems to be still animated, but visually the animation is paused.

I **can't** influence on HTML/CSS outside my `iframe`, how to fix the animations?

Comment: Kindly post your code.. So that we can help

Comment: github link is broken, `iframe` `src` value is pointing to `localhost` (`http://localhost/learn/frame.html`).

Comment: Can you try with `visibility:inherit;` while showing the div again, instead of `visible`.

Comment: Here is a working demo - http://www.aziznatour.com/temp/iframe-animation/ - the OP failed to mention that the bug manifests when you make the **iframe** invisible. It seems like a browser bug or maybe designed this way to improve performance

Comment: The problem is I can't change this behavior of a third-party site ( hiding wrapper of iframe), but i have about 10 animations on the page and it's ugly when they stops.

Comment: I put an issue on Chromium bugtracker, it was markerd as "Bug-Regression". Does it mean that it's a bug but not feature of Chrome? And how long do you think can take to fix it? I never used browser bug tracker bewfore and dont know what to expect. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=612436

Comment: @DanilShilov good job reporting the issue to chromium bug tracker. `Bug-Regression` means that the expected result used to work in the past but has problems now after a certain update - I'm not sure how long this is going to take. We'll stay tuned and please update this thread if you have any new information.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `opacity: 0` instead of `visibility: hidden` it will work without any problems:

```js
$('button').on("click", function() {
  $("#myiframe").toggleClass('invisible');
});
```

```css
.invisible { opacity: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>iFrame:</h2>
<iframe id="myiframe" style="border:2px solid red;" width="250" height="250" src="http://www.aziznatour.com/temp/iframe-animation/iframe.php"></iframe>
<br>
<button>Toggle iFrame Visibility</button>
```

---

Since you cannot modify the HTML/CSS I found another solution: use jQuery to rotate the `div` instead of CSS `animation` keyframes.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Testing iFrame CSS Animation when visibility is toggled</title>
   <style>.invisible { visibility: hidden; }</style>
</head>
<body>
   <h2>iFrame:</h2>
   
   <iframe id="myiframe" style="border:2px solid red;" width="250" height="250" src="http://www.aziznatour.com/temp/iframe-animation/iframe-jq-ani.php"></iframe>
   <br>
   <button>Toggle iFrame Visibility</button>
   
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
   <script>
      $('button').on("click", function(){
          $("#myiframe").toggleClass('invisible');
      });
   </script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

I used the **[jQuery Rotate](http://jqueryrotate.com/)** plugin - here is how your `iframe` source would be like:

```js
// VERSION: 2.3 LAST UPDATE: 11.07.2013
/*
 * Licensed under the MIT license: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *
 * Made by Wilq32, wilq32@gmail.com, Wroclaw, Poland, 01.2009
 * Website: http://jqueryrotate.com
 */

(function($) {
    var supportedCSS,supportedCSSOrigin, styles=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].style,toCheck="transformProperty WebkitTransform OTransform msTransform MozTransform".split(" ");
    for (var a = 0; a < toCheck.length; a++) if (styles[toCheck[a]] !== undefined) { supportedCSS = toCheck[a]; }
    if (supportedCSS) {
      supportedCSSOrigin = supportedCSS.replace(/[tT]ransform/,"TransformOrigin");
      if (supportedCSSOrigin[0] == "T") supportedCSSOrigin[0] = "t";
    }

    // Bad eval to preven google closure to remove it from code o_O
    eval('IE = "v"=="\v"');

    jQuery.fn.extend({
        rotate:function(parameters)
        {
          if (this.length===0||typeof parameters=="undefined") return;
          if (typeof parameters=="number") parameters={angle:parameters};
          var returned=[];
          for (var i=0,i0=this.length;i<i0;i++)
          {
            var element=this.get(i);
            if (!element.Wilq32 || !element.Wilq32.PhotoEffect) {

              var paramClone = $.extend(true, {}, parameters);
              var newRotObject = new Wilq32.PhotoEffect(element,paramClone)._rootObj;

              returned.push($(newRotObject));
            }
            else {
              element.Wilq32.PhotoEffect._handleRotation(parameters);
            }
          }
          return returned;
        },
        getRotateAngle: function(){
          var ret = [];
          for (var i=0,i0=this.length;i<i0;i++)
          {
            var element=this.get(i);
            if (element.Wilq32 && element.Wilq32.PhotoEffect) {
              ret[i] = element.Wilq32.PhotoEffect._angle;
            }
          }
          return ret;
        },
        stopRotate: function(){
          for (var i=0,i0=this.length;i<i0;i++)
          {
            var element=this.get(i);
            if (element.Wilq32 && element.Wilq32.PhotoEffect) {
              clearTimeout(element.Wilq32.PhotoEffect._timer);
            }
          }
        }
    });

    // Library agnostic interface

    Wilq32=window.Wilq32||{};
    Wilq32.PhotoEffect=(function(){

      if (supportedCSS) {
        return function(img,parameters){
          img.Wilq32 = {
            PhotoEffect: this
          };

          this._img = this._rootObj = this._eventObj = img;
          this._handleRotation(parameters);
        }
      } else {
        return function(img,parameters) {
          this._img = img;
          this._onLoadDelegate = [parameters];

          this._rootObj=document.createElement('span');
          this._rootObj.style.display="inline-block";
          this._rootObj.Wilq32 =
            {
              PhotoEffect: this
            };
          img.parentNode.insertBefore(this._rootObj,img);

          if (img.complete) {
            this._Loader();
          } else {
            var self=this;
            // TODO: Remove jQuery dependency
            jQuery(this._img).bind("load", function(){ self._Loader(); });
          }
        }
      }
    })();

    Wilq32.PhotoEffect.prototype = {
      _setupParameters : function (parameters){
        this._parameters = this._parameters || {};
        if (typeof this._angle !== "number") { this._angle = 0 ; }
        if (typeof parameters.angle==="number") { this._angle = parameters.angle; }
        this._parameters.animateTo = (typeof parameters.animateTo === "number") ? (parameters.animateTo) : (this._angle);

        this._parameters.step = parameters.step || this._parameters.step || null;
        this._parameters.easing = parameters.easing || this._parameters.easing || this._defaultEasing;
        this._parameters.duration = 'duration' in parameters ? parameters.duration : parameters.duration || this._parameters.duration || 1000;
        this._parameters.callback = parameters.callback || this._parameters.callback || this._emptyFunction;
        this._parameters.center = parameters.center || this._parameters.center || ["50%","50%"];
        if (typeof this._parameters.center[0] == "string") {
          this._rotationCenterX = (parseInt(this._parameters.center[0],10) / 100) * this._imgWidth * this._aspectW;
        } else {
          this._rotationCenterX = this._parameters.center[0];
        }
        if (typeof this._parameters.center[1] == "string") {
          this._rotationCenterY = (parseInt(this._parameters.center[1],10) / 100) * this._imgHeight * this._aspectH;
        } else {
          this._rotationCenterY = this._parameters.center[1];
        }

        if (parameters.bind && parameters.bind != this._parameters.bind) { this._BindEvents(parameters.bind); }
      },
      _emptyFunction: function(){},
      _defaultEasing: function (x, t, b, c, d) { return -c * ((t=t/d-1)*t*t*t - 1) + b },
      _handleRotation : function(parameters, dontcheck){
        if (!supportedCSS && !this._img.complete && !dontcheck) {
          this._onLoadDelegate.push(parameters);
          return;
        }
        this._setupParameters(parameters);
        if (this._angle==this._parameters.animateTo) {
          this._rotate(this._angle);
        }
        else {
          this._animateStart();
        }
      },

      _BindEvents:function(events){
        if (events && this._eventObj)
        {
          // Unbinding previous Events
          if (this._parameters.bind){
            var oldEvents = this._parameters.bind;
            for (var a in oldEvents) if (oldEvents.hasOwnProperty(a))
              // TODO: Remove jQuery dependency
              jQuery(this._eventObj).unbind(a,oldEvents[a]);
          }

        this._parameters.bind = events;
        for (var a in events) if (events.hasOwnProperty(a))
          // TODO: Remove jQuery dependency
          jQuery(this._eventObj).bind(a,events[a]);
        }
      },

      _Loader:(function()
      {
        if (IE)
          return function() {
            var width=this._img.width;
            var height=this._img.height;
            this._imgWidth = width;
            this._imgHeight = height;
            this._img.parentNode.removeChild(this._img);

            this._vimage = this.createVMLNode('image');
            this._vimage.src=this._img.src;
            this._vimage.style.height=height+"px";
            this._vimage.style.width=width+"px";
            this._vimage.style.position="absolute"; // FIXES IE PROBLEM - its only rendered if its on absolute position!
            this._vimage.style.top = "0px";
            this._vimage.style.left = "0px";
            this._aspectW = this._aspectH = 1;

            /* Group minifying a small 1px precision problem when rotating object */
            this._container = this.createVMLNode('group');
            this._container.style.width=width;
            this._container.style.height=height;
            this._container.style.position="absolute";
            this._container.style.top="0px";
            this._container.style.left="0px";
            this._container.setAttribute('coordsize',width-1+','+(height-1)); // This -1, -1 trying to fix ugly problem with small displacement on IE
            this._container.appendChild(this._vimage);

            this._rootObj.appendChild(this._container);
            this._rootObj.style.position="relative"; // FIXES IE PROBLEM
            this._rootObj.style.width=width+"px";
            this._rootObj.style.height=height+"px";
            this._rootObj.setAttribute('id',this._img.getAttribute('id'));
            this._rootObj.className=this._img.className;
            this._eventObj = this._rootObj;
            var parameters;
            while (parameters = this._onLoadDelegate.shift()) {
              this._handleRotation(parameters, true);
            }
          }
          else return function () {
            this._rootObj.setAttribute('id',this._img.getAttribute('id'));
            this._rootObj.className=this._img.className;

            this._imgWidth=this._img.naturalWidth;
            this._imgHeight=this._img.naturalHeight;
            var _widthMax=Math.sqrt((this._imgHeight)*(this._imgHeight) + (this._imgWidth) * (this._imgWidth));
            this._width = _widthMax * 3;
            this._height = _widthMax * 3;

            this._aspectW = this._img.offsetWidth/this._img.naturalWidth;
            this._aspectH = this._img.offsetHeight/this._img.naturalHeight;

            this._img.parentNode.removeChild(this._img);


            this._canvas=document.createElement('canvas');
            this._canvas.setAttribute('width',this._width);
            this._canvas.style.position="relative";
            this._canvas.style.left = -this._img.height * this._aspectW + "px";
            this._canvas.style.top = -this._img.width * this._aspectH + "px";
            this._canvas.Wilq32 = this._rootObj.Wilq32;

            this._rootObj.appendChild(this._canvas);
            this._rootObj.style.width=this._img.width*this._aspectW+"px";
            this._rootObj.style.height=this._img.height*this._aspectH+"px";
            this._eventObj = this._canvas;

            this._cnv=this._canvas.getContext('2d');
            var parameters;
            while (parameters = this._onLoadDelegate.shift()) {
              this._handleRotation(parameters, true);
            }
          }
      })(),

      _animateStart:function()
      {
        if (this._timer) {
          clearTimeout(this._timer);
        }
        this._animateStartTime = +new Date;
        this._animateStartAngle = this._angle;
        this._animate();
      },
      _animate:function()
      {
        var actualTime = +new Date;
        var checkEnd = actualTime - this._animateStartTime > this._parameters.duration;

        // TODO: Bug for animatedGif for static rotation ? (to test)
        if (checkEnd && !this._parameters.animatedGif)
        {
          clearTimeout(this._timer);
        }
        else
        {
          if (this._canvas||this._vimage||this._img) {
            var angle = this._parameters.easing(0, actualTime - this._animateStartTime, this._animateStartAngle, this._parameters.animateTo - this._animateStartAngle, this._parameters.duration);
            this._rotate((~~(angle*10))/10);
          }
          if (this._parameters.step) {
            this._parameters.step(this._angle);
          }
          var self = this;
          this._timer = setTimeout(function()
          {
            self._animate.call(self);
          }, 10);
        }

      // To fix Bug that prevents using recursive function in callback I moved this function to back
      if (this._parameters.callback && checkEnd){
        this._angle = this._parameters.animateTo;
        this._rotate(this._angle);
        this._parameters.callback.call(this._rootObj);
      }
      },

      _rotate : (function()
      {
        var rad = Math.PI/180;
        if (IE)
          return function(angle)
        {
          this._angle = angle;
          this._container.style.rotation=(angle%360)+"deg";
          this._vimage.style.top = -(this._rotationCenterY - this._imgHeight/2) + "px";
          this._vimage.style.left = -(this._rotationCenterX - this._imgWidth/2) + "px";
          this._container.style.top = this._rotationCenterY - this._imgHeight/2 + "px";
          this._container.style.left = this._rotationCenterX - this._imgWidth/2 + "px";

        }
          else if (supportedCSS)
          return function(angle){
            this._angle = angle;
            this._img.style[supportedCSS]="rotate("+(angle%360)+"deg)";
            this._img.style[supportedCSSOrigin]=this._parameters.center.join(" ");
          }
          else
            return function(angle)
          {
            this._angle = angle;
            angle=(angle%360)* rad;
            // clear canvas
            this._canvas.width = this._width;//+this._widthAdd;
            this._canvas.height = this._height;//+this._heightAdd;

            // REMEMBER: all drawings are read from backwards.. so first function is translate, then rotate, then translate, translate..
            this._cnv.translate(this._imgWidth*this._aspectW,this._imgHeight*this._aspectH); // at least center image on screen
            this._cnv.translate(this._rotationCenterX,this._rotationCenterY);   // we move image back to its orginal
            this._cnv.rotate(angle);          // rotate image
            this._cnv.translate(-this._rotationCenterX,-this._rotationCenterY);  // move image to its center, so we can rotate around its center
            this._cnv.scale(this._aspectW,this._aspectH); // SCALE - if needed ;)
            this._cnv.drawImage(this._img, 0, 0);       // First - we draw image
          }

      })()
      }

      if (IE)
      {
        Wilq32.PhotoEffect.prototype.createVMLNode=(function(){
          document.createStyleSheet().addRule(".rvml", "behavior:url(#default#VML)");
          try {
            !document.namespaces.rvml && document.namespaces.add("rvml", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml");
            return function (tagName) {
              return document.createElement('<rvml:' + tagName + ' class="rvml">');
            };
          } catch (e) {
            return function (tagName) {
              return document.createElement('<' + tagName + ' xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft.com:vml" class="rvml">');
            };
          }
        })();
      }

})(jQuery);

var rotation = function (){
  $("#rotate").rotate({
    angle:0,
    animateTo:360,
    callback: rotation,
    easing: function (x,t,b,c,d){        // t: current time, b: begInnIng value, c: change In value, d: duration
      return c*(t/d)+b;
    }
  });
}
rotation();
```

```css
      #rotate {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: limegreen;
        margin: 3em;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rotate"></div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/8qbq53fd/

Comment: I dont have any chances to change any js or css outside my iframe(visibility:hidden made by third-party JS). May i fix it only inside of my page?

Comment: @DanilShilov use jQuery to animate instead of CSS, see my updated answer.

Comment: It may help, but there tonns of css animation in my project and i dont really want to remake them with JS.